# Catching Error With Custom Rest API For FireStore Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have been watching a tutorial on making a Rest API for Firestore which appears to work but I cannot figure out how to catch an error.

The code below basically uses an end point to retrieve a document id from the firestore database.
The client uses javascript fetch to call the API.

I am trying to workout how to return something back to the client from the API if the document id is not there. I thought I might get a 404 status returned but I always get status 200.

This is the API code I used

```
app.get("/api/read/:id", (req, res) => {

(async () => {

    try {

        const document = db.collection("users").doc(req.params.id);
        let product = await document.get();
        let response = product.data();

        return res.status(200).send(response);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res.status(500).send(error);
    }

})();

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that the 404 message is for the server itself not being found (though I do need to brush up on my error codes).

---

However, if you're looking to check to see if a document exists there's a command specifically for that demonstrated in the [examples in the firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

Comment: Thank you, the examples in the docs were very helpful